# In Python, how to solve 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docxtpl'

Tags: python, docxtpl

I have installed `pip install docxtpl` with no errors. Previously I have ran programs with no erros. But I am getting this weird error of no module found. Don't know what to do?

Installation:
[image]

Nomodule error on CMD prompt when ran a py scrript
[image]

Comment: Usually this error is caused by having several different installations of Python on your system, and the `pip` and `python` commands don't agree on which version to use.  So `pip` might have installed the module for, say, Python 3.8, but your `python` command is using Python 3.9.

Comment: @JohnGordon your comment made so sense. Yes! even I got this doubt. I am installing by saying `pip3` but I don't know if I am calling right one when I say just `python file_name.py` in the CMD.  Guess! what, I opened my Spyder IDE and ran the same. It ran like cham. I am surprised but happy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do
`pip3 install docxtpl`

You can also use `pip list` or `pip3 list` to see all installed modules

Comment: Yes! I did that but did not work. Help me one thing here. I am installing on anaconda prompt and running the program on CMD as `python file_name.py`. Am I doing correct?

Comment: try launching the program with ```python3 file_name.py```

Comment: Did not work. Guess! what, I opened my Spyder IDE and ran the same. It ran like cham. I am surprised but happy.